# Simplest Angular js timepicker pop up

Tags: angularjs, timepicker

Hello All Can Anybody suggest me a simple timepicker popup for angular js,
I tried
Following timepicker
http://embed.plnkr.co/2ReOvuuhtNNcgtmWycOt/
http://www.mytechtip.com/2014/03/angularjs-timepiker-popup-ui-bootstrap.html
 but getting the injection errors, Is there a simplest way to implement it.?

You can suggest any simple timepicker popup to me, considering that I am new to angular js
[image]

Comment: check out this  http://plnkr.co/edit/uA3Ide?p=preview and may i know what are those errors you got with above?

Comment: I have added the snapshot of the error, please check it once

Comment: this error for link one or link two??

Comment: have you  refereed position .js code??

Comment: Yes, I have given the the path where I have placed position.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject `timepicker` in your app.

Like this:

```
angular.module('timepickerDemo', [ 'timepickerPop' ]).controller(
     'DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.time1 = new Date();
      $scope.showMeridian = true;
});
```

Comment: Which js is needed to inject this dependency?

Comment: For better solution you can use

Comment: clock-picker/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.js
vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

Comment: how to disabled textbox to not allow user to enter manually and how to set the interval time of the minutes?

Comment: how to set start and end time and interval as well?